# inequality about characteristic function

Tags: probability, integration, inequality, improper-integrals

Let $X$ be a random variable with density $f(x)=|x|^{-3}1_{|x|\ge1}$ and $\phi_{X}(t)=E[e^{itX}]$. Show that $\forall t\in[-1,1] $ $$|\phi_{X}(t)-1-t^2log|t||\le3t^2$$
I noticed that $E[X]=0$, so $|\phi_{X}(t)-1-t^2log|t||=|E[e^{itX}-1-itX-t^2log|t|]|$. But $1,itX$ are the first two terms  of the Taylor series of $e^{itX}$. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems the following.

$$\phi_{X}(t)=E[e^{itX}]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{itx}f(x)dx=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{itx}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{itx}}{|x|^3}1_{|x|\ge1}dx=$$ $$2\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{itx}+e^{-itx}}{x^3}dx=4\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{cos (xt)}{x^3}dx,$$

and the last integral can be estimated by different methods.

Comment: For instance, by the [Laplace method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), see also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614546/71850) example.

Comment: can you help me a little more?

Comment: I am not a specialist in Laplace’s method too, :-( so let’s hope that an analyst will come about and point a simple way to estimate the integral. :-)